# HspellPy installation

Tags: installation, pip, spelling

I am trying to install HspellPy package (using google colab) :
pip install HspellPy
(https://pypi.org/project/HspellPy/)
I get :

```
Collecting HspellPy
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/fb/d56f7809bae4a8376bc79974559a99c7deca3b3fe039acb4a4d67abd7f39/HspellPy-0.1.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: HspellPy
Building wheel for HspellPy (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for HspellPy
Running setup.py clean for HspellPy
Failed to build HspellPy
Installing collected packages: HspellPy
Running setup.py install for HspellPy ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_msu45vm/HspellPy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_msu45vm/HspellPy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-lyfnm7ww/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I looked up some fixes to "ERROR: Failed building wheel for HspellPy" but onthing helped, and since that package is not widely used i can't find anything helpful

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the main part of the error is "*fatal error: hspell.h: No such file or directory*" which means that [Hspell](http://hspell.ivrix.org.il/) is not installed (HspellPy is just a Python wrapper for Hspell which is written in C). Install Hspell; on Debian/Ubuntu try

```
sudo apt install -y hspell
```

Or compile from [sources](http://hspell.ivrix.org.il/download.html).

Then retry `pip install HspellPy`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install hspell as it is dependency for HspellPy.

I recommend to compile the source directly and make sure to compile with enable-linginfo, as I wrote in pypy in the package description and in github README file.
https://github.com/eranroz/HspellPy

In case you compile directly from sources, in some environments the upstream project (hspell) fail to compile and you need to replace:
require "PrefixBits.pl";

to:
require "./PrefixBits.pl";
in binarize-desc.pl and genprefixes.pl

Comment: The observation with the wrong PrefixBits import was very helpful!. I had problems installing it in a container (had to downgrade from python3.10 to 3.8 and compile hspell from sources)
In the end my steps were:
```wget http://hspell.ivrix.org.il/hspell-1.4.tar.gz && tar -xf hspell-1.4.tar.gz
&& cd /tmp/hspell-1.4
&& grep -Rl -e PrefixBits.pl | xargs sed -i 's#require "PrefixBits.pl";#require "./PrefixBits.pl";#'
&& ./configure --enable-shared --enable-linginfo && make && make install
&& export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/```

After this I installed HspellPy (pip install HspellPy).